# Meaning of and に and くる in「 A」と「B」に同じグループのものがくる

Tags: meaning, particle-に

I'm reading a definition of にしても〜にしても:

> 「AにしてもBにしても」は「Aの場合{ばあい}もBの場合も、どちらの場合でも」という意味{いみ}を表{あらわ}す文型{ぶんけい}です。**「AにしてもAないにしても」になる場合と、「A」と「B」に同{おな}じグループのものがくる場合があります**

This example:

> N１を受{う}けるにしても受けないにしても、毎日{まいにち}しっかり勉強{べんきょう}しなくちゃ

has that pattern 「AにしてもAないにしても」and it means "You should study hard daily whether you take the N1 or not". Here A would be 受ける and B 受けない.

The only thing I can think of is 'This is a situation where either A or B is going to happen' but I can't match this to the definition.

Should I see it as:

> [「A」と「B」]に同じグループのものがくる場合があります
>
> It's a situation where a thing from [group same as A and B] will come.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「A」と「B」に同じグループのものがくる場合があります。

To break down the sentence...

「A」と「B」に　-- into "A" and "B"
同じグループのもの -- (two) items of the same group / items that belong to the same group
くる -- come / are placed
場合があります -- there are cases where... / in some cases, ...

Put together:

> There are cases where (two) items of the same group are placed in "A" and "B".

---

Example of 「AにしてもAないにしても」になる場合：

> 行く**にしても**行か**ないにしても**、返事だけはしておかないと。
>   (Regardless of) **whether** you're going **or not**, you should at least give them a reply.

Example of 「A」と「B」に同じグループのものがくる場合：

> 英検を受ける**にしても**TOEICを受ける**にしても**、毎日しっかり勉強しておかなきゃ。
>   **Whether** you're taking 英検 **or** TOEIC, you should study hard daily.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by "How can I fix that?", but if you needed an example of a the case of the 「A」と「B」に同（おな）じグループ, what I think they probably meant　that you could use the しても　in a case like

レタスにしてもきゅうりにしても野菜は体にいいです。